# Searching for specific metadata in maps

Tags: osu

I know it's possible to search for one metadata like so:
[image: osu screenshot]

But, I wanted to know how I could search for a map with an AR in the range of 5 and 7 or an AR of 5 or more and a CS of 4 or less.
I know I can look at the metadata in the top left, but I don't want to do that to wade through sometimes thousands of maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're able to just put the filters in one after another just like how you had it in the screenshot.

So when looking for a map with an AR above 5 and a CS less than 4 you can just type:

```
ar>5 cs<4
```